# How to solve the error "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"?

Tags: php

I think this code is right, but it does not work properly.

I am trying to updating data but it outputs an error. I think this problem is seen while binding, my guess may be wrong!

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

What is the problem?

```
class.user.php{
 public function edit_user($uname,$umail,$upass,$uaddress,$uglevel,$ustate,$userpic){
        try
        {
            $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $stmt_edit = $this->conn->prepare('UPDATE users SET
                                             user_name=:uname,
                                             user_email=:umail,
                                             user_pass=:upass,
                                             user_address=:uadddress,
                                            user_grade_level=:uglevel,
                                             ustate=:ustate,
                                             user_photo=:upic
                                             user_id=:user_id
                                       WHERE user_id=:user_id');
            $stmt_edit->bindparam(":uname", $uname);
            $stmt_edit->bindparam(":umail", $umail);
            $stmt_edit->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);
            $stmt_edit->bindparam(":uaddress", $uaddress);
            $stmt_edit->bindparam(":uglevel", $uglevel);
            $stmt_edit->bindparam(":ustate", $ustate);
            $stmt_edit->bindparam(":upic", $userpic);

            if($stmt_edit->execute()){
                ?>
                <script>
                    alert('Successfully Updated ...');
                    window.location.href='user_list.php';
                </script>
            <?php
            }

            return $stmt_edit;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();`enter code here`
        }
    }

}
//edit_user.php
if(isset($_POST['btn_save_updates']))`enter code here`
{
    $uname = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uname']);
    $umail = strip_tags($_POST['txt_umail']);
    $upass = strip_tags($_POST['txt_upass']);
    $uaddress = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uaddress']);
    $uglevel = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uglevel']);
    $ustate = strip_tags($_POST['txt_ustate']);

    $imgFile = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];//image file
    $tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];//directory
    $imgSize = $_FILES['user_image']['size'];//image file size

    if($imgFile)
    {
        $upload_dir = 'LMS_students/'; // upload directory
        $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension
        $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions
        $userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;
        if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions))
        {
            if($imgSize < 5000000)
            {
                unlink($upload_dir.$edit_row['user_photo']);
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);
            }
            else
            {
                $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large it should be less then 5MB";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // if no image selected the old image remain as it is.
        $userpic = $edit_row['user_photo']; // old image from database
    }


    // if no error occured, continue ....
    if(!isset($errMSG))
    {

        $user -> edit_user($uname,$umail,$upass,$uaddress,$uglevel,$ustate,$userpic);

    }
    else{
        ?>
        <script>
            alert('user couldnt be Updated');
            window.location.href='user_list.php';
        </script>
    <?php
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: `user_id=:user_id` i guess this line has an issue .. Are you passing user_id ?

Comment: like the error said you just don't have the same number of binded param, you miss :userid

Comment: You can't reuse placeholders either, though why you'd want to update `user_id` when it's not changing, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below point

1) You have not bind `user_id` .

2) `user_photo=:upic, // missing comma`

3) `user_address=:uadddress, // typo ddd`

You have not added user_id in function so, need to add that, then use in `bindparam`